# Entity Resolution from domain-specific Ontology

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, named-entity-recognition

What is the best approach to identify Entities and extract them from texts using my own domain-specific ontology?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into any of the IBM Watson services on IBM Bluemix? I wrote up a brief summary of all the available services on my blog; see: [Meet the real Watson](http://codyburleson.com/web/guest/blog/-/blogs/meet-the-real-watson). I know that Watson Knowledge Studio allows you to identify entities and relationships in existing texts through a visual GUI. I also know that the AlchemyAPI service has entity recognition, but I have not personally learned how to train it with my own ontology (so, I cannot say for certain whether or not it's possible).

I noticed also that others have provided some interesting tips and links on Quora under the question, Natural Language Processing: [What APIs and libraries can extract dates, times, places, and other logistical information from unstructured text?](https://www.quora.com/Natural-Language-Processing-What-APIs-and-libraries-can-extract-dates-times-places-and-other-logistical-information-from-unstructured-text)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Stanbol to build a domain specific entity recognition pipeline for custom vocabularies: https://stanbol.apache.org/docs/trunk/customvocabulary.html